# OrderedDict Field in mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, dictionary, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with Django for my website.

I imported some articles into my mongoengine, it has a field `text` which is an ordered dict with chapter names as keys and chapter content as values, like this:

```
{"text":{
"Introduction":"...",
"Algorithm":"...",
"Conclusion":"...",
"References":"..."}
}
```

But when I use `text = DictField()` as a field of the Document, I got the keys ordered by the charaters， which is different from the original order:

```
{"text":{
"Algorithm":"...",
"Conclusion":"...",
"Introduction":"...",
"References":"..."}
}
```

I want to have the original order of the dict, but it seems like mongoengine does not offer an OrderedDictField.

Is there any solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: A dict may not be a good idea here when you consider the update options. Say you wanted to add "Function" for instance after "Algorithm". The underlying MongoDB storage has no way to do that without replacing the entire dict. If you used arrays ( list ) however the positions are set and there are operations to allow you to "insert at position" in the storage engine. You might want to consider your use case here as if position is important this probably should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

As of today there is no support for ordereddict, consider using a ListField to store 2-tuples

```
[
    ("key1", "value1"),
    ("key2", "value2"),
]
```

Which can be turned into an `OrderedDict` easily (`OrderedDict(that_list)`)